# Tags for personal use

Tags: discussion, feature-request

`Requirement`: To maintain a set of 'private' tags which are visible to the user alone.

Right now, I put nearly all important things under 'favorites'. This feature might not be a feasible option as it might be a huge system overload(?). Are there other browser level tools that can do this job?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It would be very useful, if I could sort my favorites by tags.

Comment: related feature-request: [private notes about a question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/13940/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a cloud bookmark thing.

- [Pocket](https://getpocket.com/) supports tags for items, and has apps available for Android and iOS. (I use Pocket regularly, but not for MSE.)
- [Delicious](https://delicious.com/) has been around since forever.
- [Wikipedia gives you a list of more options](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_social_bookmarking_websites).

Use your browser bookmarks. I know that Firefox at least supports tagging of bookmarks. (Chrome... I am not sure.)

Comment: I also use Pocket to carry small change, my phone and on occasion keys to my office.

Comment: @Asaf, I have upgraded to Pocket 2.0, also called Backpack.

Comment: @Willie Wong: Both 'pocket' and 'delicious' serve the purpose (allow tagging a question(its webpage)). Thanks for your suggestions.